# Expression for value minus a running total

Tags: sql

I have 2 values - 1 is the gross value of a Purchase order and the 2nd value is running sum gross value of the invoices linked to that PO. I now need to take the Po value minus the Invoice value - but the fields do not like the simple totalgrossvaluehome1-totalgrossvaluehome1_1 - as the 2nd field is a running sum. I've tried to add in ruuning sum to the expression but nothing returns. I'm sure I can do this to get the variance between these 2 fields but no idea how. Can anyone help?

Comment: And your sql query is?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.